# Remove duplicates lines but not blank lines in Sublime Text

Tags: windows, windows-10, sublimetext3

I know that you can remove duplicate lines by doing `Edit>Permute Lines>Unique`. But that will remove blank(empty) lines. I would like not to remove them, so blank lines will stay(essentially empty space).

Comment: Close voters: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Permute Selections. First, open the Find menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or **`Find → Find…`**) and make sure the Regex, Wrap, and Highlight matches buttons are selected. In the search field, enter `^.+\n`. This matches the beginning of the line `^`, 1 or more characters of any type `.+`, and the newline character(s). Therefore, it will select any line that is NOT just a newline. Note that this will select lines that contain only whitespace, for example a tab character followed by a newline.

[image: Regex search]

Next, hit the <kbd>Find All</kbd> button to select each line individually.

[image: Find all]

Finally, select **`Edit → Permute Selections → Unique`** and all duplicate lines will be erased, leaving all blank lines behind.

[image: Unique lines plus blank lines]